# How to match the whole string in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to math the whole string like `*[123]*` and `*[[123]]*`

I do not know how to use elisp to match these two different string.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need all numbers or 123 as a string, here a scenario matching all numbers:

```
   (progn
  (re-search-forward "\\*+\[[0-9]+]+\\*+")
  (message "%s" (match-string-no-properties 0)))
```

With grouped output:

```
(progn
  (re-search-forward "\\(\\*+\\)\\(\\[+\\)\\([0-9]+\\)\\(]+\\)\\(\\*+\\)")
  (message "%s %s %s %s %s"
           (match-string-no-properties 1)
           (match-string-no-properties 2)
           (match-string-no-properties 3)
           (match-string-no-properties 4)
           (match-string-no-properties 5)))
```

Comment: I want to match the whole word not the number. For the first string `*[123]*` I want to match the asterisk , the left bracket , the number , the right bracket and the asterisk.